# ¿Como separo una columna en varias columnas por el tipo de respuesta en tablas dinámicas de excel?

Tags: excel

Saludos tengo el siguiente problema y no logro encontrar una solucion.
Tengo la siguiente tabla dinámica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaría tener algo como esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo lo anterior no me sirve pues lo que hice fue poner a la variable V1 en los campos de columnas y al cambiar a V2 me sale otros valores. A mi lo que me gustaría es ver cuantos hay de 1, 2, 3 y 4 para cada una de las variables pero no se que poner en el campo columna para que esto suceda y como mencione poner V1 no sirve por que los valores que da no son los correctos y si uno poner V2 los cambia y yo ocupo los reales.

Se puede hacer esto de alguna forma? dividir las respuestas en columnas por el tipo de respuesta que hay?
Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Ejemplo de datos

```
v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
1   4   3   4   3
1   2   1   2   4
2   2   1   3   2
3   4   1   1   3
2   4   1   2   3
1   1   4   3   1
2   4   3   3   2
4   4   1   4   3
4   2   1   3   3
3   4   4   2   2
1   1   4   3   1
1   4   3   3   3
3   2   2   4   3
3   2   1   2   2
3   2   1   4   1
1   4   3   2   2
2   1   3   1   4
1   4   1   1   1
4   2   1   2   2
4   3   4   1   3
3   1   4   3   1
1   2   1   1   2
2   3   1   3   4
1   2   4   4   1
4   1   1   4   3
2   2   1   1   2
3   3   4   2   3
4   2   2   2   2
4   3   3   3   4
3   4   4   4   4
3   1   2   2   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con una tabla dinámica no vas a poder hacerlo ahora por el diseño de tus datos. Para poder hacer lo que quieres, tus datos deberían estar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si los datos los pones así, sí podrías hacer la tabla dinámica que quieres:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no rediseñas tus datos, no vas a poder hacer lo que quieres.

Otra opción es utilizar CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO en tus datos de origen y hacerte un cuadro resumen que cuente eso que quieres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las fórmulas que yo he usado en cada fila para hacer las cuentas son:

```
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($A$11:$A$41;B$1)
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($B$11:$B$41;B$1)
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($C$11:$C$41;B$1)
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($D$11:$D$41;B$1)
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($E$11:$E$41;B$1)
```

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, no modo lo voy a hacer con formulas